# Directed Graph Traversal with Networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a large directed graph (networkx.DiGraph()) that is composed of several directed trees, each with one root. I also have a function that takes in a certain graph and outputs some of its nodes. Here are the operations I would like to do.

1. Given an arbitrary directed forest, and a level provided, cut the graph at that given level, and run each of the newly created subgraphs through the function.
2. If the root of the newly created graph shows up in the output of the function, proceed to remove that subgraph from the graph. Else, remove all of its descendants from the graph.

I know that was complicated, so let's run through a sample run.

For the sake of simplicity, let our arbitrary graph be one tree, rather than several. I'll choose the nx.balanced_tree(2,4,create_using=nx.DiGraph()) as my graph. The edgelist for that graph is shown below

```
(0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,7),(3,8),(4,9),(4,10),(5,11),(5,12),(6,13),(6,14),
(7,15),(7,16),(8,17),(8,18),(9,19),(9,20),(10,21),(10,22),(11,23),(11,24),(12,25),(12,26),
(13,27),(13,28),(14,29),(14,30)
```

Note that 0 has level 0, 1-2 have level 1, 3-6 have level 2, 7-14 have level 3, and 15-30 have level 4.

Let's say I input 3 into my program. Then, I take each node in level 3 as a root of its own subgraph, and process each one in my program. So, the subgraphs represented as

```
Subgraph 1: (7,15),(7,16)
Subgraph 2: (8,17),(8,18)
etc
```

Will be inputted into my function. Let the function output 7 as a node, but not 8. Then, the nodes 7, 15, 16 should all be removed, and the nodes 17 and 18 should be removed, but not 8.

I apologize for this being complicated, but in reality, I think its a bunch of simple steps concatenated together.  However, my looping approach is definitely un-optimal. What is the best approach?

Comment: It's not really an _arbitrary directed graph_ if you know it's a forest, is it?

Comment: True, my bad, that's sloppy on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the solution I am going to present is a little hacky but I am open to suggestions for more optimizations.

First we will create a dummy graph for testing

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.balanced_tree(2,4,create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Next, we will [dfs_tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree) API of networkx (use the latest version) and use the `depth_limit` attribute to extract tree upto depth `n` and `n+1` where `n+1` is the depth entered by the user (since it starts indexing depth at 1)

```
T1 = nx.dfs_tree(G, source=0,depth_limit=3)   #here n=3
T1_edges = list(T.edges())
#[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 7), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14)]
```

Then do the same for depth `n+1`

```
T2 = nx.dfs_tree(G, source=0,depth_limit=4)
T2_edges =list(T2.edges())
#[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 7), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (7, 16), (7, 15), (8, 17), (8, 18), (9, 19), (9, 20), (10, 21), (10, 22), (11, 24), (11, 23), (12, 25), (12, 26), (13, 27), (13, 28), (14, 29), (14, 30)]
```

Now take the XOR of these two lists

```
edges_left = list(set(T1_edges).symmetric_difference(T2_edges))
#[(14, 30), (11, 23), (10, 21), (7, 16), (11, 24), (7, 15), (10, 22), (9, 20), (12, 25), (13, 28), (8, 17), (14, 29), (12, 26), (13, 27), (8, 18), (9, 19)]
```

These are the edges at level 3. Now extract the nodes at these levels

```
nodes_at_level = set([x[0] for x in edges_left])
#{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
```

Then use [bfs_tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_tree) to extract tree at these nodes

```
for n in nodes_at_level:
    tree = nx.bfs_tree(G, n)
    print tree.edges()              #Do whatever you want with those subgraphs

#[(7, 16), (7, 15)]
#[(8, 17), (8, 18)]
#[(9, 19), (9, 20)]
#[(10, 21), (10, 22)]
#[(11, 24), (11, 23)]
#[(12, 25), (12, 26)]
#[(13, 27), (13, 28)]
#[(14, 29), (14, 30)]
```

Comment: I like this a lot! I was actually intending on using the single_shortest_path function to generate a list of nodes at a given level, but this works well too!

Comment: However, the main thing I need help with is popping nodes. I need to either be able to pop all of the nodes of a subgraph (e.g. 7, 15, 16) or all but the one at the given level (e.g. 15, 16, but not 7). Do you have any clues as to how to do that efficiently?

Comment: Also, when doing XOR, I think simply taking a non-symmetric difference would also suffice, no?

Comment: Your welcome! If this answer helped you out can you please upvote and Mark it as the correct one :-) Now coming back to your query,not sure about non symmetric distance need to check that. For popping of nodes, just take list of nodes from bfs tree and remove all but first element using remove node method